# Error 405 not allowed on HttpPost in Asp.net core 3.1 web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, http-status-code-405

When i try to post the raw text with postman the server answer 405 not allowed. I try to add

app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

services.AddCors();

without any solution.

Whis is the code of the application:

```cs
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class VideoWallController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<ValuesController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<ValuesController>
        [HttpPost]
        public string prova([FromBody] VideoCallBack test)
        {
            return "true;";
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void teststring(string test)
        {

        }

        // PUT api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

[image: Error on postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,as `maghazade` said,`there are two endpoints for the post method`.You can try to use `[HttpPost("teststring")]` as `ferhrosa` said.You can also add `[action]` to  `[Route("api/[controller]")]`,so that routes of actions will include their action names.If you add other actions with post method,the routes will not conflict anymore.

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class VideoWallController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<ValuesController>/Get
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<ValuesController>/Get/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<ValuesController>/prova
        [HttpPost]
        public string prova()
        {
            return "true;";
        }
        // POST api/<ValuesController>/teststring
        [HttpPost]
        public void teststring([FromBody]string test)
        {

        }

        // PUT api/<ValuesController>/Put/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<ValuesController>/Delete/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

And if you want to pass `string test` from Body,you need to add `[FromBody]` and select `JSON` in postman.
[image]

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reach that endpoint using the `/teststring` suffix, you need to put that in the endpoint template:

```cs
[HttpPost("teststring")]
public void teststring(string test)
{
}
```

Or, as @maghazade said, you can just reach the endpoint using the controller URL, without a suffix: `https://localhost:44336/api/videowall`

Also, the CORS settings are not needed to access the API using Postman. CORS is used only to configure the API access through a web application running on a web browser.